# Software composition using "components" - Clarification needed

Tags: oop, design-patterns, composition, software-design

I read a nice definition for software composition [here](http://www.mendeley.com/research/research-directions-software-composition/#page-1). It says

*Software composition is the construction of software applications from components that implement abstractions pertaining to a particular problem domain*

Is it the construction of these *abstractions* where design patterns fit in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a higher level abstraction.  Patterns solve common object-oriented problems.

Abstraction, encapsulation, and information hiding are pertinent at the level of individual components.  You can do the latter without ever employing patterns.

Comment: +1 Thanks for clearing this up for me. So when *building* a component then, could you argue that you would turn to design patterns for the development of this component (In an ideal scenario)?

Comment: Depends on the pattern.  Some require lots of interacting components (e.g. Facade); some are intended for individual components (e.g. Singleton, Decorator).